# Why are null and undefined of the type DOMWindow?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

When you run the following code in the browser, or in Node.js, you get the expected outcomes listed in the comments:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(undefined); // "[object Undefined]"
Object.prototype.toString.call(null); // "[object Null]"
```

When you run that code in PhantomJS, however, the output is `[object DOMWindow]` in both cases.

This seems strange, since `undefined` and `null` are both native types. The `typeof` operator appears to work as it does in other environments (including the `typeof null === "object"` quirk), so it would appear that PhantomJS does at least have the concept of the undefined type:

```
typeof undefined; // "undefined"
```

It also claims that `Object.prototype.toString` contains native code, which may indicate that Phantom itself isn't doing anything to modify the implementation (I don't know if that's the case or not though - I haven't been able to find anything useful in the source):

```
Object.prototype.toString.toString(); // "function toString() { [native code] }"
```

So why does PhantomJS not use (or at least expose) the correct `[[Class]]` property values for `null` and `undefined`, and is there a way I change that? I know I could use a different method to determine type, but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: That sounds like a bug.

Comment: @SLaks - Yeah, that was my first thought, but it's not like this is unusual or rarely-found code... I very much doubt that I'm the first to come across it and yet I've found no reference to it anywhere in the issue tracker.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what kind of problems are you trying to solve or which conditions are affected by this behavior?

Comment: @AriyaHidayat - I've got a set of unit tests, some of which are testing a `getType` function which uses the technique mentioned in my question to return the type of its argument. Those tests pass in all environments except Phantom, which is annoying because it means I'm having to patch `Object.prototype.toString` to get a working build script (the build script runs the unit tests automatically with Phantom).

Comment: I use a similar technique and it already had special case for null `if (o === null) { return 'null' }` - with a reference to old IEs, my problem was with `undefined `- I guess the easiest workaround is to check `undefined` as a corner case too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a combination of two things. A script is executed within a web page and therefore the global object is the `window` object, as evidenced from:

```
console.log(this.toString()); // [object DOMWindow]
```

In addition, there is a problem with that version of JavaScript implementation which falsifies the object prototype chain under the above condition.

This is likely going to be fixed in some future version.

Comment: Thanks for providing an official answer :) I noticed that the global object was `window` and assumed that had something to do with it, but digging through the source of both Phantom and JSC was tedious and didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Is there an issue in PhantomJS or JSC?

Comment: Every good bug gets even better with age - can you update on any progress please?

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit I'm kind of reaching here, but the [MDN article on `Object.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) mentions:

> Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 toString() called on null returns [object Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined], as defined in the 5th Edition of ECMAScript and a subsequent Errata. See [Using toString to detect object type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString_to_detect_object_type).

The linked section then describes the construct `Object.prototype.toString(null)` that you're using. So it seems like being able to sensibly stringify `null` and `undefined` is a new(-ish) addition/correction to Javascript that the PhantomJS engine (Apple's JavaScriptCore, at who knows which version) doesn't implement yet. That said, this works correctly in Safari 6, so it might be worth to report this as a bug, asking for ES5 compliance.

Answer (score -1):

if it's just that 2 types, i think you can just surround your issue with this.

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(obj){

    if(typeof(obj) == "undefined"){
        return "[object Undefined]";
    }

    if(typeof(obj) == "null"){
        return "[object Null]";
    }

    return obj.toString();

}
```

Comment: As I've said in my question, I know I could change the way I get the type, but I'd rather not have to. Plus, your code won't work because you've lost the native method which would be needed instead of the `obj.toString()` call. Also note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function, and it returns "object" for `null` (that's the quirk I mention in my question).

Comment: Please correct your answer `typeof null === 'object'`